# Error when using flushleft in equation environment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, errors

I practice in LaTeX and encountered such a problem:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.28        \begin{flushleft}
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}


\usepackage{geometry} % Меняем поля страницы
\geometry{left=2cm}% левое поле
\geometry{right=1.5cm}% правое поле
\geometry{top=1cm}% верхнее поле
\geometry{bottom=2cm}% нижнее поле

\begin{document}


  30.4 в \\
  $\sqrt{\frac{5x-1}{x+3}} =  2$ \\
  $\frac{5x-1}{x+3} = 4, x\neq -3$ \\
  $5x-1 = 4x+12$ \\
  $x = 11$ \\  
  Ответ: 11.\\ \\
  30.6 в \\

  $\sqrt{3x+4} = \sqrt{5x+2} $
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{flushleft}
  \begin{cases}
      3x+4 \ge 0 \\
      5x+2 \ge 0
  \end{cases}
  \begin{cases}
    x\ge -1.25 \\ 
    x \ge  -0.4
  \end{cases}
  \rightarrow D(x) \in [-0.4; +\infty) \\
\end{flushleft}
\end{equation*}

  $3x+4=5x+2$ \\
  $2 = 2x$ \\
   $x = 1$ \\
   $x \in D(x)$ \\
   Ответ: 1. \\ \\
   30.11 в \\

   $\sqrt{15+3x} = 1-x,    x\le 1 \Rightarrow D(x) \in (-\infty; 1] $\\
  $15+3x = x^2-2x+1$ \\
  $x^2 - 5x - 14 = 0$ \\
  $D = 25+4 \cdot 14 = 25 + 56 = 81$ \\
  $x_1 = \frac{5+9}{2} = 7$ \\
  $x_2 = \frac{5-9}{2} = -2$ \\
  $x_1 \not\in D(x)$ \\
  Ответ: -2. \\ \\
  30.18 в \\
  $\sqrt{x^2+x+1} = x+2, x\ge -2 \rightarrow D(x) \in [-2; +\infty) $ \\
  $x^2+x+1 = x^2 + 4x + 4$ \\
  $3x = -3$ \\
   $x = -1$ \\
   Ответ: -1. \\ \\
   30.21 в \\
   $\sqrt{3x+1} + \sqrt{x-4} = 2\sqrt{x} $ 
   \begin{equation*}
     \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{cases}
        3x+1 \ge  0 \\
      x-4 \ge  0 \\
      x \ge  0 \\
    \end{cases}
    \begin{cases}
      x \ge  -\frac{1}{3} \\
      x \ge  4 \\
      x \ge  0\\
    \end{cases}
    \Rightarrow D(x) \in [4; +\infty) \\
  \end{flushleft}
   \end{equation*}
   $3x+1+x-4 +2\sqrt{(3x+1)(x-4)} = 4x$ \\
   $4x-3+2\sqrt{3x^2-11x -4 } = 4x $ \\
   $2\sqrt{3x^2-11x-4}=3 $ 
   $12x^2-44x-16=9$ \\
   $12x^2-44x-25 = 0$ \\
   $D_1 = 22^2 + 12 \cdot 25 = 484 +300 = 784$ \\
   $x_1 = \frac{22+28}{12} = \frac{25}{6} = 4\frac{1}{6}$ \\
   $x_2 = \frac{22-28}{12} = -\frac{1}{2}$ \\
   $x_2 \not\in D(x)$ \\
   Ответ: $4\frac{1}{6}$\\
\end{document}
```

I tried to put $$ in systems of equations, but that didn't help.
What is the reason for this error? And how can you indent the solution so that it can be visually distinguished from the job number?

Comment: Flushleft is a text environment, it has no place inside displayed math, remove them and it compiles just fine.

Comment: @daleif You beat me for 10 sec :-)). I'm working on the code before. Can I complete the answer or remove it? Addendum: please look that the tag is wrong.

Comment: @Sebastiano add some explaing text to it as well

Comment: @daleif Done! I have added some explanations of the mistakes and suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have added also `T1 fontenc` for possible problems with accents (or special charathers) of russian language or characters;
2. I have added this `\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}` https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/russian/russianb.pdf to declare your Russian language as the main text (see page 4).
   [image]
3. I have delete the main problem `\begin{flushleft} ...\end{flushleft}` into an enviroment `\begin{equation}....\end{equation}` because the `flushleft` environment is used for align to left a text and not into an equation (All the text in between `\begin{flushleft}` and `\end{flushleft}` is left-justified.).

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}


\usepackage{geometry} % Меняем поля страницы
\geometry{left=2cm}% левое поле
\geometry{right=1.5cm}% правое поле
\geometry{top=1cm}% верхнее поле
\geometry{bottom=2cm}% нижнее поле

\begin{document}


  30.4 в \\
  $\sqrt{\frac{5x-1}{x+3}} =  2$ \\
  $\frac{5x-1}{x+3} = 4, x\neq -3$ \\
  $5x-1 = 4x+12$ \\
  $x = 11$ \\  
  Ответ: 11.\\ \\
  30.6 в \\

  $\sqrt{3x+4} = \sqrt{5x+2} $
  \begin{equation*}
   \begin{cases}
      3x+4 \ge 0 \\
      5x+2 \ge 0
  \end{cases}
  \begin{cases}
    x\ge -1.25 \\ 
    x \ge  -0.4
  \end{cases}
  \rightarrow D(x) \in [-0.4; +\infty) \\
\end{equation*}

  $3x+4=5x+2$ \\
  $2 = 2x$ \\
   $x = 1$ \\
   $x \in D(x)$ \\
   Ответ: 1. \\ \\
   30.11 в \\

   $\sqrt{15+3x} = 1-x,    x\le 1 \Rightarrow D(x) \in (-\infty; 1] $\\
  $15+3x = x^2-2x+1$ \\
  $x^2 - 5x - 14 = 0$ \\
  $D = 25+4 \cdot 14 = 25 + 56 = 81$ \\
  $x_1 = \frac{5+9}{2} = 7$ \\
  $x_2 = \frac{5-9}{2} = -2$ \\
  $x_1 \not\in D(x)$ \\
  Ответ: -2. \\ \\
  30.18 в \\
  $\sqrt{x^2+x+1} = x+2, x\ge -2 \rightarrow D(x) \in [-2; +\infty) $ \\
  $x^2+x+1 = x^2 + 4x + 4$ \\
  $3x = -3$ \\
   $x = -1$ \\
   Ответ: -1. \\ \\
   30.21 в \\
   $\sqrt{3x+1} + \sqrt{x-4} = 2\sqrt{x} $ 
   \begin{equation*}
        \begin{cases}
        3x+1 \ge  0 \\
      x-4 \ge  0 \\
      x \ge  0 \\
    \end{cases}
    \begin{cases}
      x \ge  -\frac{1}{3} \\
      x \ge  4 \\
      x \ge  0\\
    \end{cases}
    \Rightarrow D(x) \in [4; +\infty) \\
    \end{equation*}
   $3x+1+x-4 +2\sqrt{(3x+1)(x-4)} = 4x$ \\
   $4x-3+2\sqrt{3x^2-11x -4 } = 4x $ \\
   $2\sqrt{3x^2-11x-4}=3 $ 
   $12x^2-44x-16=9$ \\
   $12x^2-44x-25 = 0$ \\
   $D_1 = 22^2 + 12 \cdot 25 = 484 +300 = 784$ \\
   $x_1 = \frac{22+28}{12} = \frac{25}{6} = 4\frac{1}{6}$ \\
   $x_2 = \frac{22-28}{12} = -\frac{1}{2}$ \\
   $x_2 \not\in D(x)$ \\
   Ответ: $4\frac{1}{6}$\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your number 1 might be a bit harsh, especially if it is a novice. But I agree one should never use ``\\`` in the text. Hard to teach that to a student the hard way yesterday. Been a whice since I've seen that many wrong ``\\`` in a document

Comment: @daleif aahah :-) When I first started to write in 2002 in LaTeX I used // but then I abandoned the double backslash after reading so many manuals. I removed the first advise.

Comment: I never mentioned one could use // or /newline in the text anywhere in my larex book (in Danish), precisely because that was the single most common mistake I saw in the n docs that I helped edit. Nowadays it us misuse of /text that is the most common

Comment: I understand how to use it